# Send messages to multiple Service Bus topics and then send it to cosmos db

Tags: javascript, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I am trying to send messages to multiple topics at once and then using an Azure Functions App send it to Cosmos DB ? Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

See here for examples on how to use Service Bus output bindings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#output---javascript-example

You should be able to create multiple output bindings for multiple topics as well like this (didn't test it)

```
{
    "bindings": [
        {
            //...
            "direction": "in"
        },
        {
            "name": "outputSbQueue1",
            "type": "serviceBus",
            "queueName": "testqueue1",
            "connection": "MyServiceBusConnection",
            "direction": "out"
        },
        {
            "name": "outputSbQueue2",
            "type": "serviceBus",
            "queueName": "testqueue2",
            "connection": "MyServiceBusConnection",
            "direction": "out"
        }
    ],
    "disabled": false
}
```

Output binding for CosmosDB see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#output---javascript-examples

Comment: In Azure Functions there is a way to hard-code the topic and subscription but externally i.e. outside the function. How will changing the bindings change that?